# Modifying EKParticipantStatus in EventKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, ekevent, ekeventkit

In my calendar based app in iOS, i sync all event from device calendar.
i create one event with me as participant from another gmail.

now i want to change "EKParticipantStatus" like going, maybe or NO.

but, this property is readonly in EKParticipant. i have checked all other related forum also. no clue to solve my requirement.

Please help me to solve this.

```
/*!
@property   participantStatus
@abstract   The status of the attendee.
@discussion Returns the status of the attendee as a EKParticipantStatus value.
*/

@property(nonatomic, readonly) EKParticipantStatus participantStatus;
```